# Why is Cypress not checking checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, cypress

In my cypress runner, I can see that it is successfully finding the checkbox, as I can see it has the `type="checkbox"` attribute.  I also noticed that by manually clicking the checkbox, its "value" attribute became "true", so I tried using `invoke('attr', 'value', 'true')` which also "succeeds" but the text box remains unchecked.  Not sure what I am missing.  There are no `onClick` events that I can see that might uncheck it immediately after checking either.

My code:

[image]

What it returns:

[image: return checkbox element]

Comment: Maybe there is another (hidden) checkbox, check that you are clicking the correct one

Answer (score 0):

I guess it may depend on the way that the checkbox is implemented. I had the same issue and the way that I found to solve it was by using `.click({force: true})` instead of `check({force: true})`